# How can I capture the left and right arrows and have them call an AngularJS function?

Tags: angularjs

In my application I would like to capture when a user clicks on a left or right button and then have it call a function in a controller.

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: There's a discussion about this at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/vXqVOKcwA7M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a `ng-keypress` to a top level DOM element, say `body`, and check if the character code for each click is left or right. You can [this](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) site to find which character codes you need (left and right are 37 and 39). Just make sure you pass the `$event` object so you actually capture the key codes.